# Three.js TexturePass texture being stretched

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, post-processing

I'm just picking up three.js, I've been playing around with this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mask#webgl_postprocessing_masking

I don't know if this is intended but the textures used in the demo are stretched out to fill the window. You'll notice the image being deformed if you try resizing the window.

I would like for the texture to act the same as the `cover` CSS background property, where the image covers all the available sceenspace but without being stretched.

I've read that textures can be manipulated with `texture.repeat` and `texture.offset` but these seem to have no effect when the texture is being passed into the `TexturePass()`.

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(env.img + 'desk.jpg')
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter

texture.repeat.set(1,2)

var texturePass = new TexturePass( texture )
```

the `texture.repeat` seems to be ignored completely.

This is the code for the exemple above that I'm using as a boilerplate. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_postprocessing_masking.html

Is there something else I have to do beforehand with the texture? Any help would be appreciated, I've been looking all over the internet but there seems to be very little on Three postprocessing examples such as TexturePass.

Comment: Unfortunately, `.repeat` property is only accounted for when using the texture as a UV map. AFAIK, there's no built-in procedure to do what you are expecting. However it can be easily achieved using custom shaders. Check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/54y0enLv/).

Comment: @TheSloth `scene.background = texture` honors the `texture.repeat` setting.

Comment: Thank you both, that really helped. I ended up going with ScieCode suggestion as I was planning on using shaders with the texture anyways. @ScieCode I can't accept your comment as an answer but if I could I would.